# Load content on tab selected (Foundation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 6 Tabs.  I have a javascript question. Here is my html for a 3 tab layout.

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="myTabs">     
    <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1 Info</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title" ><a href="#panel2">Tab 2 Info</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title" ><a href="#panel3">Tab 3 Info</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="myTabs">
    <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel3">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

The tabs work great! However, I want to load content into Tab 3 only when clicked.  I will be using ajax to load the content.  Foundation 6 docs provide a javascript event that fires when ANY tab is clicked on.  See below:

```
 $('#myTabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
      console.log('Those tabs sure did change!');
 });
```

I need an event to fire ONLY when panel3 is selected. How to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use condition inside **'change.zf.tabs'** event, like this:

```
$('#myTabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {

  if($('#panel3:visible').length){
    console.log('Tab 3 is now visible!');
  }

});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For Foundation 6 (current version is 6.2.1) you should use the following code to get the ID of the changed tab.

```
$('#myTabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function()
{
    var tabId = $('div[data-tabs-content="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').find('.tabs-panel.is-active').attr('id');
    alert(tabId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add condition on tab `id` you want to load content when it's selected, e.g :

```
$('#myTabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
   if ($(this).attr('id') == 'panel3')
   {
        //Load content here 
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` for me always returns id of `ul` element: "myTabs"

Comment: Does the event data itself not contain information about which tab has been switched to? How unhelpful if not.

Answer (score 0):

I just came to this problem.

Ended using:

`$(this).find('.is-active a').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some luck with this in Foundation 6:

```
$('.tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function(event, tab){
    console.log(tab.children('a').attr('id'));
    console.log(tab.children('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Foundation 6 I used:

```
$("#section-tabs").on('change.zf.tabs', function (event, tab) {
        var tabId = tab.attr("id");
})
```